# Can a character benefit from 2 different fighting styles (e.g. Protection and Defense) at the same time?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighting-style

All fighters get the Fighting Style feature at 1st level. A Champion fighter also gets a second fighting style at 10th level.

Can 2 different martial fighting styles be used together at the same time? 
For example, if a Champion fighter had the Protection and Defense fighting styles, would they gain the benefits of both?

Answer (score 15):

## Yes

Quoting from the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=3):

> **Can a fighter have two fighting styles active at once?
> Dueling and Defense, for example.** You can benefit from
> more than one Fighting Style option at a time, as long as
> they don’t have conflicting requirements, as Dueling and
> Great Weapon Fighting do.

The requirements for Defense and Protections are wearing armour and wielding a shield, which are decidedly not conflicting.

Comment: Wielding armor and wearing a shield, however... a sign things have really gone off the rails.